Prove that a complement graph for a simple, non-connected graph with two even degrees has an Eulerian path
Trying to answer a question from a test and couldn't get it right. Would love for your help.

Let $G$ be a simple, non-connected graph with $n$ vertices $(n \geq 2)$. Assuming there are exactly two vertices with an even degree, prove that there is a non-cycle Eulerian path in the complement graph.

I tried to solve it using the condition for a Eulerian path (having exactly two vertices with an odd degree), but I couldn't figure out why the complement would have to have two vertices with an odd degree. And I haven't seen a satisfying proof for the Eulerian path condition anyway.

The handshaking lemma tells us that any graph has an even number of odd degree vertices. Since $n$ has the same parity as the number of odd degree vertices in $G$, we know $n$ is even. Observe that $\deg_G(v)+\deg_{\bar{G}}(v) = n-1$ for all vertices $v$. Thus, for all vertices $v$, the parity of $\deg_G(v)$ is the opposite of that of $\deg_{\bar{G}}(v)$, so $\bar{G}$ has exactly two vertices of odd degree. To conclude that $\bar{G}$ has an Eulerian path, you also need to observe that the complement of a disconnected graph is connected.
